# Attempting to use proof irrelevance without creating ill-typed terms

Tags: coq

To illustrate the issue I am facing let us assume we have a predicate on `nat`:

```
Parameter pred : nat -> Prop
```

Let us assume further that we have a type which encapsulates data, as well as a proof that the encapsulated data satisfies a certain property. For example:

```
Inductive obj : Type :=
  | c : forall (n:nat), pred n -> obj
  .
```

Now we would like to regard two objects `c n p` and `c m q` to be the same objects as long as `n = m`, regardless of the proofs involved to build them. So let us introduce a proof irrelevance axiom:

```
Axiom irrel : forall (P:Prop) (p q:P), p = q.
```

Now given this axiom, it is expected that the equality `c n p = c m q` be provable for `n = m` :

```
Theorem obvious : forall (n m:nat) (p: pred n) (q:pred m),
  n = m -> c n p = c m q.
```

Now I have been playing around with this for a while, and none of the typical 'rewrite' tactics can work as they create ill-typed terms. I am guessing the theorem should be true within Coq's type theory (given the proof irrelevance axiom) but probably involves some trick unknown to a beginner. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
Theorem obvious n m (p: pred n) (q: pred m) :
  n = m -> c n p = c m q.
Proof.
  intros ->.
  rewrite (irrel _ p q).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

#### Explanation

Let me show how one can use information containing in error messages to come up with a solution:

```
Theorem obvious n m (p: pred n) (q: pred m) :
  n = m -> c n p = c m q.
Proof.
  intros E.
  Fail rewrite E.
```

At this point we get the following error message:

> ```
> The command has indeed failed with message:
> Abstracting over the term "n" leads to a term fun n0 : nat => c n0 p = c m q
> which is ill-typed.
> Reason is: Illegal application: 
> The term "c" of type "forall n : nat, pred n -> obj"
> cannot be applied to the terms
>  "n0" : "nat"
>  "p" : "pred n"
> The 2nd term has type "pred n" which should be coercible to "pred n0".
> ```

The `rewrite` tactic tried to build the proof term using `eq_ind_r` lemma. Let us look at its type:

```
eq_ind_r
     : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Prop),
       P x -> forall y : A, y = x -> P y
```

`rewrite` tries to build the following term:

```
@eq_ind_r _ m (fun x => c x p = c m q) (subgoal : c m p = c m q) n E.
```

which is ill-typed:

```
Fail Check @eq_ind_r _ m (fun x => c x p = c m q).
```

> The term `"p"` has type `"pred n"` while it is expected to have type `"pred x"`.

This means that the link between `n` and `pred n` has been lost at this point and we can restore it by saying explicitly that `x` and `p` must comply with each other by generalizing over `p`:

```
Check @eq_ind_r _ m (fun x => forall (p : pred x), c x p = c m q).
```

The above means we can proceed to finish the proof in the following manner:

```
  revert p.
  rewrite H; intros p.
  rewrite (irrel _ p q).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The original version of the code uses intro-pattern `intros ->` to achieve the effect of the longer `intros E; revert p; rewrite E; intros p.` for this particular case.

Comment: Hi Sven, my pleasure :)